# Oracle External Procedures with Delphi DLL

Tags: oracle, delphi, dll, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have been trying to configure the "External Procedures" Feature for my Oracle Database 18c on Windows 10.

The documentation claims, to set up this feature, it is basically just necessary to set the environment values in `extrproc.ora` - which in my case is just one line of: `SET EXTPROC_DLLS=ANY` (for testing purposes).

I have created a DLL to test my configuration by using Delphi with the following code:

```
library testdll;

function Sum(x, y: Integer): Integer; stdcall;
begin
  Result := x + y;
end;

function Subtract(x, y: Integer): Integer; stdcall;
begin
  Result := x - y;
end;

procedure TEST; stdcall;
begin

end;

exports
  TEST,
  Sum,
  Subtract;

begin

end.
```

So my first question would be: Do I need to compile the DLLs as x64 or as x86? Also, is the calling convention `stdcall` compatible with Oracle 18c?

Furthermore I have created a Library Alias in my database using:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE LIBRARY MySchema.TESTDLL AS 'C:\testdll.dll'
```

The external procedure has been published by

```
create or replace PROCEDURE TESTPROCEDURE
AS LANGUAGE C 
NAME "TEST"
LIBRARY TESTDLL;
```

Now that I have everything setup on the database, I tried calling the procedure:

```
begin
TESTPROCEDURE();
end;
```

But when I tried calling it, I get the following Error:

```
ORA-06520: PL/SQL: Fehler beim Laden der externen Library
ORA-06522: Unable to load DLL
ORA-06512: in "MySchema.TESTPROCEDURE", Zeile 1
ORA-06512: in Zeile 2
06520. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: Error loading external library"
*Cause:    An error was detected by PL/SQL trying to load the external
           library dynamically.
*Action:   Check the stacked error (if any) for more details.
```

Info:

- The database spawns the `extproc.exe` properly, after I call the procedure

How do I get this work properly and are Delphi DLLs even compatible?

This is my `listener.ora` file:

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\oracle\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\NETWORK\ADMIN\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = XE

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\oracle\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\oracle\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\bin\oraclr18.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 127.0.0.1)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

And this is my tnsnames.ora file:

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\oracle\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\NETWORK\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 127.0.0.1)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

LISTENER_XE =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 127.0.0.1)(PORT = 1521))


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
```

Any ideas what could be wrong with my configuration?

Edit:
This is the .c dll example code from the database:

```
/*
** Copyright (c) 1997 by Oracle Corporation
**
** NAME
**   EXTERN.C 
**
** DESCRIPTION
**   Sample Windows NT External Procedure: find_max 
**
*/

#include <windows.h>

#define NullValue -1

/*
  This function simply returns the returns the larger of x and y.
*/

long __declspec(dllexport) find_max(long    x, 
                    short   x_indicator, 
                                    long    y, 
                        short       y_indicator, 
                    short       *ret_indicator)
{
   /* It can be tricky to debug DLL's that are being called by a process
      that is spawned only when needed, as in this case.  
      Therefore try using the DebugBreak(); command.  
      This will start your debugger.  Uncomment the following line and
      you can step right into your code.
   */
   /* DebugBreak();  */

   /* first check to see if you have any nulls */
   /* Just return a null if either x or y is null */

   if ( x_indicator==NullValue || y_indicator==NullValue) {
      *ret_indicator = NullValue;   
      return(0);
   } else { 
      *ret_indicator = 0;        /* Signify that return value is not null */
      if (x >= y) return x;
      else return y;
   }
}
```

And this is the make.bat file:

```
REM USAGE: just type MAKE
if (%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%)==(IA64) goto win64_ia64
if (%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%)==(AMD64) goto win64_amd64
 cl -I. /LD -Zi extern.c /link msvcrt.lib /nod:libcmt /DLL
 goto fi
:win64_ia64
 cl /DWIN64 /D_WIN64 /DSS_64BIT_SERVER /D_IA64_=1 -I. /LD -Zi extern.c /link msvcrt.lib /nod:libcmt /DLL
 goto fi
:win64_amd64
 cl /GS- /DWIN64 /D_WIN64 /DSS_64BIT_SERVER /D_AMD64_=1 -I. /LD -Zi extern.c /link msvcrt.lib /MACHINE:AMD64 /nod:libcmt /DLL
 goto fi
:fi
```

Comment: Aren't there any examples in the Oracle documentation?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan There is a `.c` sample. However I can't compile it since I don't have the (correct) C compiler. I suppose my configuration of the database is not quite correct.

Comment: Which compiler are you meant to have? But anyway, that will tell you about the calling convention. As for 32 or 64 bit, that depends on the host process. Your DLL must match the host process. If we could see the C example we could tell you whether or not you will be able to replicate it in Delphi.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have added the code and the make.bat to my question. Also, Oracle DB 18c for Windows is only available for x64

Comment: OK, so the answers are that the code uses `cdecl` and is 64 bit, and accepts 5 arguments rather than 2. I suspect that you can do the rest from here.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan `cdecl` did the trick! Thank you very much. This is the actual answer. Also, anything I need to consider, when using `cdecl`?

Comment: What do you mean by "anything I need to consider"?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan stuff like cleaning up stack/registers, etc. - any tips are welcome =)

Comment: Don't invent problems where none exist.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I appreciate your help. Please consider answering this question to accept your solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information provided, I can see the following:

- The C example is compiled as a 64 bit DLL.
- The C example does not specify a calling convention and so uses the default which is `cdecl`.
- The example C functions accept 5 arguments, but your functions accept only 2.

Comment: In 64 bit (Windows) it is very likely not `cdecl` but the standard Win64 calling convention. No need to specify anything in Delphi, since that should use the same calling convention. There is not much choice, in the Win64 target. Even if you specify `stdcall` or `register`, it will be ignored. In other words: in Win64, the calling convention cannot be the problem.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Good point. It's a solid discipline to specify calling convention just in case one day you compile for a different platform which does have multiple conventions.